# How to prevent Firefox add-ons from being installed?

Tags: firefox

Firefox asks before installing add-ons but how can I make it so the user is not allowed to install add-ons?

Comment: This is old, but about:config has remained pretty consistent, so this might answer your question: https://serverfault.com/questions/115774/is-there-a-way-for-administrators-to-disable-users-from-installing-firefox-exten

Comment: If you mentioned the goal of this exercise there might be ways to answer this which are not generic.

Answer (score 5):

Add-ons are not installed system-wide but by each user just for herself. And they are stored within their home directory.

So there is no way (apart from making the profile directory read-only) to prevent a user from installing them.

In case you want to experiment with the profile: visit `about:profile` within Firefox to find out where your profile is stored. But keep in mind (as Dan stated in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217412/how-to-prevent-firefox-add-ons-from-being-installed/1217419?noredirect=1#comment2047071_1217419)) that nothing can prevent a user to create and use a new profile for her browser.

Comment: Is there a specific folder that add-ons live within each user’s home directory that you can just limit write capabilities?

Comment: @blonded On my system the extensions are in `~/.mozilla/firefox/MY_PROFILE_ID.default/extensions/` (where `MY_PROFILE_ID` is `q2iqu6ru` in my case).

Comment: @blonded I'm not sure what's your goal for preventing browser addons from being installed. even if you set the extensions directory to read-only, users can create a new firefox profile and install add-ons again.

Comment: @Dan Fair enough— this is for my parents personal computer. They have a tendency to install random add ons. I don’t suspect they’ll figure out how to create a new profile. There’s a bigger behavioral lesson to reinforce to not approve add on installations in the first place, but I’m getting there